# Cannot compile code from Arduino WIFI shield example

Tags: arduino-uno-wifi

I'm trying to launch the piece of code in this Wifi example:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFiConfig
via Arduino.cc online editor, but I'm getting those errors:

```
/home/ubuntu/opt/libraries/latest/wifinina_1_2_0/src/utility/spi_drv.cpp:87:24: error: 'PINS_COUNT' was not declared in this scope
```

and

```
/home/ubuntu/opt/libraries/latest/wifinina_1_2_0/src/utility/spi_drv.cpp:97:15: error: 'NINA_GPIO0' was not declared in this scope
```

Do someone has an idea of how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those kinds of errors are usually caused by the selection of an incorrect hardware in the IDE.

Choosing a correct board in the IDE will solve the compilation issue.

Since you said that you used the Arduino.cc online editor, I pasted your code into the editor.

You did not say which Arduino board or which WiFi module you are using, so I chose `Arduino Uno WiFi` board as a starting point.

Compiling the code produced the same errors as in the post.

Next I chose `Arduino Uno WiFi Rev2` board, and compiled without errors.